# Cube question without coordinates, cross sections and planes

Tags: geometry

We have a cube with corners $ABCDA_1B_1C_1D_1$. The points $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ lie above the square $ABCD$. We also have a plane that goes through the middle of line $BC$, through the middle of square $ABA_1B_1$, through the middle of $A_1B_1C_1D_1$. At what ratio does the plane cut line $AB$.

What I did, I've put the cube into the coordinate system $B(0,0,1), A_1 (0,1,0) \text{ and } A(0,0,0)$, $D(1,0,0)$ and then it was pretty easy to solve. I just got the equation of the plane and then solved for intersection of the line that goes through AB, to get the point. Then I knew the ratio.

My question is, how to solve this problem without putting the cube into the coordinate system?

SOLUTION: solution should be that the plane cuts AB in ratio 3:1

Comment: Presumably you also don't want to use vectors (despite saying vector BC)

Comment: yes, line BC...

Comment: If the middle of square $ABA_1B_1$ means its center then you have only two points a point on $BC$ and the center of square $ABA_1B_1$. That may not lead to a unique solution.

Comment: @MathLover There are three points. The middle of $ABA_1B_1$ and middle of $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ besides middle of BC.

Comment: oh ok, then yes.

Comment: Doesn't the plane pass through $B$?

Comment: @DavidK The solution should be that the plane cuts AB in ratio 3:1

Comment: Please show your full solution -- coordinates of points, equation of plane. I thought I had a clear picture in my head but it does not match your result.

Comment: @DavidK I answered and provided the info bellow.

Comment: I found my point of confusion: "through the middle of $A_1B_1C_1D_1$" means through the middle of a face. I misread the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly quickly:

(1) the plane (call it $\Pi$) also passes through the centre $M_{ABC_2D_2}$ of square $ABC_2D_2$ ($C_2,D_2$ are the reflection of $C,D$ in line $AB$).  This is just extending $M_{A_1B_1C_1D_1}M_{ABB_1A_1}$ to meet the bottom plane $ABCD$.

(2) So the line $M_{BC}M_{ABC_2D_2}$ lies in $\Pi$.  This line intersects AD at $X$ where $AX=\frac32 AD$ and $X$ is opposite to $D$.

Now look at the configuration $A,B,X,M_{BC}$ and you have similar (right-angled) triangles $\triangle AXY$ and $\triangle YBM_{BC}$ where $Y$ is the intersection of diagonals, i.e., intersection of $AB$ with $\Pi$.  So $AY:YB=AX:BM_{BC}=3:1$.

Comment: You could also look at the quadrilateral $M_{BC}BM_{ABC_2D_2}M_{AB}$ where $M_{AB}$ is the midpoint of $AB.$ This is a parallelogram, one diagonal lies on $AB$ and the other lies in the plane $\Pi.$ Their intersection $X$ is therefore the midpoint of each diagonal, and $BX$ is half the distance $BM_{AB}$ which is half of $AB$.

Comment: @DavidK I thought about writing that way but decided against it.  It is either do the extending to my $X$ and read off the ratio, or don't extend and do the mid-point of half segment.

Comment: Your way is fine too. And your way gets the $3:1$ ratio directly rather than via $2:1:1$.

Answer (score -1):

In response to the question how I solved with coordinate system:

Let's say:

$$AA_1 = (0,0,1) = c$$
$$AB = (0,1,0) = a$$
$$AD = (1,0,0) = b$$

Now we get all three points as mentioned above:

$$P_1 = c + (1/2)a + (1/2)b = (1/2,1/2,1/2)$$
$$P_2 = (1/2)c + (1/2)b = (0,(1/2),(1/2))$$
$$P_3 = a + (1/2)b = ((1/2),1,0)$$
Now we get two vectors $P_2P_3$ and $P_2P_1$. When we do cross product we get: $$n = (1,-2,-1)$$

The equation of the plane is thus: $$x - 2y - z = \frac{-3}{2}$$
Because: $\text{We use the second point and get:}0*1 + (1/2)*(-2)+(1/2)(-1) = \frac{-3}{2}$

Now we know that $AB$ is on  $y$ axis , or the second coordinate as we may call it is a parameter $t$. So the equation of the line on which $AB$ is on is $y = t, x =0, z=0$, where $t$ is the parameter.

Now we input $y =t$ into the plane equation and get $$(-2t = \frac{-3}{2}\iff t =\frac{3}{4} )\implies \text{ratio is: } 1:3$$

Comment: $P_1$ should be $(1/2,1/2,1)$ rather than $(1/2,1/2,1/2).$ This didn't help when I tried to reproduce the rest of the answer.